# How to trigger same popup with multiple buttons Popper.js?

Tags: javascript, html, popper.js

How to trigger same popup with multiple buttons using Popper.js?

So i have one popup with id *popup-share* on the page. And i have for ex. 3 buttons .button--icon-share. I wrote the code below, but popup is appearing near the first button :( So wrong positioned

```
var popupShare = $('#popup-share');
  popupShare.hide();

  $('.button--icon-share').click(function(e){
    var popper = new Popper($(this), popupShare, {
      placement: 'bottom-end'
    });
    popper.scheduleUpdate();
    popupShare.show();
  });
```

Please help, if someone've faced this problem before! Thanks! :)

Comment: How would you like the popup to be positioned?

Comment: It should be at the bottom end of the button. Is button 1 clicked -then under this button, if second - under 2nd etc.

Comment: @OliverRadini i think its related with position of elements on the page. Because i have fixed header so maybe its breaking popup. And some other elements on the page have position relative

Comment: I'm finding it a little difficult to recreate what you're getting; I can only get the popup to appear right after the element which is clicked, which seems to be the desired behavior. Are you able to include any more code?